# Jenkins pipeline in hang

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to understand why the following snippet runs well and very shortly on "Console script", but hangs in a pipeline.

```
        def runningBuilds = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getView('All').getBuilds().findAll() { it.isInProgress() }
    runningBuilds.each{ value ->
        def buildUrl= value.getAbsoluteUrl()
        def runningSince= groovy.time.TimeCategory.minus( new Date(), value.getTime() )
    
        if (runningSince.hours > 1){
    
           println value.getDisplayName() +"---- ${runningSince.hours} hours:${runningSince.minutes} minutes"
           println "URL---- ${buildUrl} "
        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: this code works for me in "pipeline" type with Use Groovy Sandbox
 unchecked
you havent provided enough info to help you